# Change the selected value of the selectlist

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `selectmenu plugin` for my select list. I want to change the selected value of the selectlist using jquery. I tried :

```
               $('select').val("new selected value");
               $('select').selectmenu("value", "new selected value");
```

But both of the above are not working. Help me out please?

Comment: please send link to your plugin

Comment: http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/ here`s the link

Comment: have you tried [`jQuery.prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Doc says following

```
// read
$('select#speedA').selectmenu("value")
// write
$('select#speedA').selectmenu("value", "VALUE")
```

And this works also. [Check this out](http://jsfiddle.net/KtEaK/78/)

**EDIT**

The problem could be, your "New Value" must not be matching from list of options you have for the select list. The text should match exactly.

In my example, try changing this line 
`$('select').selectmenu("value", "An Army")`   to

```
$('select').selectmenu("value", "An Army1")
```

And see this wont work either

Answer (score 0):

`$('select').selectmenu("value", "new selected value")` should work but you have to use the index of option instead of "new selected value"

Comment: you mean `$('select').selectmenu("value", $(this).eq(0));` something like this

Comment: $('select').selectmenu("value", 0).You can find the index if you know the text in jquery using options.index()